# Is the a memory issue? c++ [code blocks][Windows]

Tags: c++, windows

My code blocks of able to compile the code below and worked well:

```
unsigned long int a=100000000000;
```

My code blocks of able to compile the code below **But my program crashed immediately after i enter the same number(100000000000)**:

```
unsigned long int a;
 cin>>a;
```

how to fix? Why the fist one is working !why not the second case?

if i entered a number more than max unsigned long int size! then why did the first work?

Comment: " _crashed immediately_ " ?

Comment: " crashed immediately " ? ! yes it did!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "crash"?

Comment: Could you please post a [mcve]? The lines alone seem pretty inoffensive...

Comment: the problem       "closes"

Comment: Yes, and closing doesn't mean crashing.

Comment: It will close when you get to the end of `main`. The console window may or may not close automatically at that point. On Windows, add `system("pause");` at the end of `main`. [Here's an online compiler playing with `unsigned long int` and `cin`.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Z3nsGxQb6v7OvPDO)

Comment: it says the there is a problem in program @JackDeeth

Comment: i will soon add screen shots!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason for crash here.

The initialization causes a warning on my compiler because of truncation of an unsigned long long value, and the read attempt simply result in an failed read and does not change the value of the variable.

Code demonstrating it (on a 32 bit machine):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    unsigned long int b=100000000000; // warning here

    unsigned long int a = 0;
    cin>>a;

    cout << "b:" << b << "(" << std::hex << b << ")" << " a:" << std::dec << a << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as expected

```
b:1215752192(4876e800) a:0
```

because as an ULL on my architecture 100000000000 is 0x174876E800 and the high order bytes have been truncated...